# Remove substring like this+immediate next character in php

Tags: php, string

```
$srt=HDD(2GB*2)qty3##HDD(4GB*2)qty4##HDD(2GB*2)qty5
```

In above example i need to replace qty+next numeric value with null

Comment: Did you try something to solve it?

Comment: What do you mean with null: 'null', ''?

Comment: @bommox Null means i want to remove it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way for such case is using `preg_replace` function:

```
$srt= "HDD(2GB*2)qty3##HDD(4GB*2)qty4##HDD(2GB*2)qty5";
$srt = preg_replace("/qty\d+?/", "", $srt);

print_r($srt);  // "HDD(2GB*2)##HDD(4GB*2)##HDD(2GB*2)"
```

For additional condition: '*replace qty3## like all with " ,"*'

```
...
$srt = preg_replace("/qty\d+?##/", " ,", $srt);
```

Comment: suppose now i need replace qty3## like all with " ," then how to write this query

Comment: @Tush, can you add your new condition to your question with a readable formatting?

Comment: suppose string contain qty2 then i want the value after qty in above it is 2

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regex replacement:

```
$srt="HDD(2GB*2)qty3##HDD(4GB*2)qty4##HDD(2GB*2)qty5";
preg_replace("/qty\\d/", "", $srt);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use preg_replace for `this+immediate next character in php`

```
<?php
  $string = 'HDD(2GB*2)qty3##HDD(4GB*2)qty4##HDD(2GB*2)qty5';
  $pattern = '/qty\w/';
  $replacement = '';
  echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```

check this : https://eval.in/606776

output is :

```
 HDD(2GB*2)##HDD(4GB*2)##HDD(2GB*2)
```

Comment: suppose now i need replace qty3## like all with " ," then how to write this query

Comment: Please Read about regular expression, you can try this at your end.

Comment: can you give me some documents where i can understand regular expression

Comment: Yes, here is very good way for leaning regex. Best of luck : http://regexone.com/